# R package check() warning: A complete check needs the 'checkbashisms' script

Tags: r, cran

Today I have tried to prepare a new CRAN update for a package and have come across a warning, while performing `devtools::check()`.

Since this warning also occurs without my changes I made to the package, I am assuming this is a new check. Unfortunately I don't really get what I am supposed to do.

This is the error message:

> A complete check needs the 'checkbashisms' script.
> See section ‘Configure and cleanup’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’
> manual.

Of course **I took a look at the section ‘Configure and cleanup’** as proposed in the warning. But still, I am not sure what to do exactly. I got, there is a `checkbashisms` Perl script I can download somewhere on the internet (but this alone won't make this message disappear). How shall I integrate this, that the message actually disappears.

Any hints or comments would be extremely helpful to me.

Here is a link to the repo of the [package](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/ridge) in case you want to clone it to reproduce the error.

Comment: It's a FAQ. It means _the RHub machine should have the script `checkbashisms` installed_ but hasn't.  Nothing your package can do about it. Or if you were running on your own machine, make sure a) `checkbashisms` is in the `$PATH` and b) executable.  In any event, it is a _local_ warning.  Use win-builder too, use RHub too.

Comment: Yes, was my own machine. WinBuilder just finished, you are correct - there is no warning there. Thanks a lot for your quick and insightful answer!

Comment: Just for anybody later on reading this question. Following Dirks advice solved the problem just perfectly. I added the `checkbashisms` perl script to `$PATH`, made it executable (important) and the warning disappeared.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, you can install checkbashisms with `sudo apt install devscripts`