# Check R package needs the 'checkbashisms' script

Tags: r, windows, r-package, cran

I just checked my package with R CMD CHECK on win-builder and I get this warning:

> A complete check needs the 'checkbashisms' script

[My package](https://github.com/stla/jackR) has a configure script. I don't get this warning with R CMD CHECK on Linux.

I searched *checkbashisms* in *Writing R extensions* but I don't understand what I have to do. It seems it's a new check, perhaps Windows-specific.

Comment: Sorry, just seen it's a dup: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/63698128/1100107> but there's no answer.

Comment: Just install the [file](https://github.com/Debian/devscripts/blob/master/scripts/checkbashisms.pl) somewhere on your `PATH`, e.g., `install -m 755 checkbashisms.pl /path/to/bin/checkbashisms` ...

Comment: Sorry, I read the question too fast and thought that you were seeing this warning locally.  Well, it does not imply a problem with your package.  It only implies that the winbuilder machine is (transiently?) does not have the script on its `PATH`.