# R CMD check A complete check needs the 'checkbashisms' script

Tags: r, package, rstudio, warnings

I am in the very early stages of writing a package using RStudio. The basic package structure was created using William Landau's `instantiate` package.
When I click on the `Check` button all appears to go well but I get two warnings, one of which reads in full:

> checking top-level files ... WARNING   A complete check needs the
> 'checkbashisms' script.   See section ‘Configure and cleanup’ in the
> ‘Writing R Extensions’   manual.

(The other warning is about something else entirely).

I have seen this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698128/r-package-check-warning-a-complete-check-needs-the-checkbashisms-script]
but still do not understand what to do. I do not know what `$PATH` is, or how to add something to it.

I also saw this answer:
[ https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2020q3/005877.html][1]

In consequence I added `_R_CHECK_BASHISMS_ = FALSE` to my `.Renviron` file but that had no effect.

What do I have to do to remove this warning?

Comment: I am not familiar with Will's `instantiate` package nor yours, but I'm going to guess that that warning is because it found what it thinks is a `/bin/sh` shell script in your package. The `checkbashisms` utility (itself a shell script) is intended to prevent somebody from making the making the mistake that a script starts with `#!/bin/sh` but actually contains BASH-isms that suggest it should start with `#!/bin/bash` instead. If you have shell scripts but they are not intended to be part of the package, you might consider the use of `./.Rbuildignore`.

Comment: @r2evans:  It needs `checkbashisms` if the package has `configure` or `cleanup` scripts.

Comment: Jeremy, if you remove the `configure` and/or `cleanup` scripts from your package, you won't get that warning.  But you might need them.  We can't tell without seeing what's in your package.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330, I've not had those scripts in my packages before, good context

Comment: Thanks from me too, @user2554330. I find that `instantiate` has included both `configure` and `cleanup` scripts as well as `configure.win` and `cleanup.win` scripts. Their only function appears to be to give an error message if my package was unable to compile or cleanup the Stan models. I'll try removing them and see what happens. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R check code wants the `configure` and `cleanup` scripts to be written without relying on the `bash` shell, because it isn't available on all systems where your package might be installed.

It uses a script called `checkbashisms` to look at those files to confirm they are written portably.  However, `checkbashisms` isn't included in R, it's assumed to be available on your system.  So you get the warning you saw if you have `configure` or `cleanup` scripts, but R can't find `checkbashisms`.

This means there are a couple of ways to stop the message.  You could install `checkbashisms` in a place where R will find it.  It uses the `PATH` environment variable to search for external programs, so you would need to make sure `checkbashisms` was installed in one of the directories listed in it.  (You can see that environment variable using `Sys.getenv("PATH")` from within R.)

Another way is to make sure your package doesn't include `configure` or `cleanup` scripts.  Those are only needed for packages that are doing complicated things, often using external libraries.  You mentioned in a comment that the automatically generated scripts were looking for Stan models.  That might mean you need those scripts.

However, unless you're writing at a fairly low level, it's probably enough for your package to depend on another package that uses Stan, e.g. `RStan`. Then if Stan can't be found, that other package will fail to load, and your package will also fail to load.  Then you can delete `configure` and `cleanup` and won't need to install `checkbashisms`.

You could also just ignore the message.  CRAN will have `checkbashisms` installed, so they won't get that message and won't block your package because of it.

Comment: I have heard from the author of the `instantiate` package. He says "The mechanism of {instantiate} relies on the configure and cleanup scripts, which means the warning is inevitable if you are checking the package locally. But you can ignore that warning because CRAN has checkbashisms installed."